# Migrating Django 1.3 to 1.10 Unwanted suffix added to admin urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

When I use any link on the admin page a "change/" suffix is added to my url's and they are not found.  Things start out OK, but after jquery is loaded RelatedObjectLookups is loaded and subsequent urls have a "/change" appended.  I've been looking at this problem for a few hours and have no idea where to go.

This is what my test server output looks like:

```
September 10, 2016 - 16:21:49
Django version 1.10.1, using settings 'adsync.settings'
Starting development server at http://192.168.56.101:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[10/Sep/2016 16:21:55] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5558
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6876
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/css/base.css/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/css/changelists.css/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3217
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/core.js/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/css/base.css/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/css/base.css/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/css/base.css/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1870
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/css/changelists.css/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/css/changelists.css/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/css/changelists.css/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1891
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/actions.js/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/urlify.js/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/core.js/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/core.js/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/core.js/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1864
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1912
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1885
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1930
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/actions.js/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/actions.js/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/actions.js/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1873
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/urlify.js/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/urlify.js/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/urlify.js/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1870
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1885
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1918
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/img/search.svg/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/img/search.svg/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/img/search.svg/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/img/search.svg/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1876
WARNING Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg/change/
Not Found: /admin/auth/user/static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg/change/
[10/Sep/2016 16:22:05] "GET /admin/auth/user/static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1882
```

You can see the early on "../base.css" is loaded, but a subsequent url searches for "../base.css/change", and it is not found.

I'm relatively new to Django and javascript.  I am good with Google searches and having no luck in finding relevant information.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you want to hear, but I would recommend upgrading Django versions one at a time from 1.3 to 1.10, using each upgrade guide along the way.

Here's the relevant breaking changes of each release statement:

[Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#backwards-incompatible-1-4),

[Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#backwards-incompatible-1-5),

[Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#backwards-incompatible-1-6),

[Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#backwards-incompatible-1-7),

[Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#backwards-incompatible-1-8),

[Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#backwards-incompatible-1-9),

[Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/#backwards-incompatible-1-10)

It looks daunting, but chances are you're not using a lot of the features that changed in every release.

Very often with technical debt, it's tempting to take shortcuts, but that usually ends up putting you in even more technical debt, especially if you're not an expert with Django.

Comment: Julien thanks for the suggestion.

I've decided on a similar but different approach.  I thought I would add the app to 1.10 a piece at a time.  I'll start with models and the admin additions.  Followed by the custom login.  Then I'll add url's and views one at a time.  At least that way it will narrow down where to look when i find an issue.

One issue with going one version of django at a time is the upgrades of all the supporting python pieces such as jquery and pycrypt.  I'm hoping bring over the app a piece at a time will keep the issues manageable.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but just wanted to respond anyway for anyone else who reads... While your approach may be manageable if the app is simple enough, you may find yourself missing bugs as things will "seem to work". The dependencies should up upgraded along with each Django upgrade, even if they aren't latest releases, following each of their upgrade paths as well. Packages often support wide ranges of Django versions, so as long as you install the highest compatible package releases as you move up Django releases, this shouldn't be as daunting as it might first seem to be.